# BitConverter.ToSingle truncates float values

Tags: c#, floating-point

When converting binary data to float values using ruby's `String#unpack` method I get the following results:

```rb
[0x7d, 0xe8, 0x80, 0xc5].map(&:chr).join.unpack('e')[0]
# => -4125.06103515625
```

This is considered the correct result.

Using C# `BitConverter.ToSingle` method I get the following result:

```cs
var firstVal = BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] {0x7d, 0xe8, 0x80, 0xc5}, 0);
// firstVal: -4125.061
```

So it seems that the value is truncated somehow.
Is there a way to extract the correct value (as in the `ruby` example) from the binary representation?

Comment: How are you printing the value?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(((double)firstVal).ToString("R"));` prints the same value as ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remember, Ruby only has one float type, and that is double-precision float. So the type of value of your ruby expression is double-precision float, analog of which in C# is "double". So if you want to get exact same number, you can do this (but I'm not sure it actually makes much sense, see @xanatos comment):

```
var firstVal = (double) BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] {0x7d, 0xe8, 0x80, 0xc5}, 0); 
// firstVal is -4125.06103515625
```

Comment: One has to wonder why the [documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/unpack) states that the `'e'` format string will return a single precision floating point number... documentation woes again and again...

Comment: @InBetween I think it states that return value is Float (the only ruby float type), but format "e" means that byte array should be treated as containing single precision float (so has 4 bytes and not 8 like double)

Comment: oh lol. I associated the "format string" to the output, not the input. Makes sense I guess...